# Align 2 divs on either side of a parent div

Tags: css

I've got the below div structure

```
<div id="news">
   <div id="innerNews">
      <div id="newsLeft" style="width:10%; height:100%"></div>
      <img id="newsThumb" src="nwes.png" width="80%" />
      <div id="newsRight" style="width:10%; height:100%"></div>
   </div>
</div>

#news{
  width:30%;
  position: relative;
}
#innerNews{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How can I get `#newsLeft` to be aligned to the left and `#newsRight` to be aligned to the right of `#news`?

Comment: Down-voter: Please care to leave a comment as to why this question was down-voted. That helps.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I think it's because this is a very basic question

Comment: I suggest you can use :before and :after here.

Comment: How to layout column elements is not hard to research. There are numerous ways to do this. This question shows a lack of search effort

Comment: @charlietfl: Nothing is impossible to find these days but you have to ask even a very simple question if you are not knowing how or when you're stuck with it.

Comment: @Bekki no...this is really easy to find. Long before this site even existed it was easy to find. Also...the answers you get will be sophmoric as there are a wide range of ways with pros and cons to each depending on your situation. Not to mention in modern browsers there are new css3 layout options like flex and columns. You are expected to do research yourself...not use SO questions as your first line of learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CSS Table

Because of your structure I'd recommend to use `display: table;` thereby  you'll get equal column height. Also depending on what you are trying to do you can substitute middle column by another `div` and set a background to it, so you would be able to place some content in it.

```css
#news {
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
}
#innerNews {
    display: table-row;
}
#newsLeft, #newsThumb, #newsRight {
    display: table-cell;
}
#newsLeft, #newsRight {
    background-color: firebrick;
    width: 11%
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
   <div id="innerNews">
      <div id="newsLeft"></div>
      <img id="newsThumb" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <div id="newsRight"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### Floating

Another way to do that is using `float: left;`. There is no point to use `float: right;` on the third div because you have total width of three blocks equal 100%: [10%][80%][10%].

```css
#innerNews {
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
}
#newsLeft, #newsThumb, #newsRight {
    float: left;
}
#newsThumb{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
#newsLeft, #newsRight {
    background-color: firebrick;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
   <div id="innerNews">
      <div id="newsLeft"></div>
      <img id="newsThumb" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <div id="newsRight"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can remove `width` from `##innerNews` to achieve certain effect, but again - it depends on what you want.

### Position

If you'd like to stick with position

```css
#innerNews {
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
#newsLeft, #newsThumb, #newsRight {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#newsLeft {left: 0;}
#newsThumb {left: 10%;}
#newsRight {left: 90%;}
#newsThumb{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
#newsLeft, #newsRight {
    background-color: firebrick;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
   <div id="innerNews">
      <div id="newsLeft"></div>
      <img id="newsThumb" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <div id="newsRight"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the css `float`, like

```
#newsLeft {
    float: left;
}

#newsRight {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do it. Use `position` attribute as required.

```css
#news{
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  position: relative;
  background:#ccc;
  margin-left:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#innerNews{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
}

#newsLeft
{
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  left:-30px;
  background:#444;
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%; height:100%
  }

#newsRight
{
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  left:230px;
  background:#444;
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%; height:100%
  }
```

```html
<div id="news">
   <div id="innerNews">
      <div id="newsLeft" >newsleft</div>
      <img id="newsThumb" src="nwes.png" width="80%" />
      <div id="newsRight" >newsright</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the point of using both inline style and stylesheet. Not much separation of concerns there

Comment: Inline stylesheet was use because it was what was given in the question. Anyway editing that.